# CS0246-The type or namespace name 'DefaultTypeParamAttribute' could not be found in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

CS0246-The type or namespace name 'DefaultTypeParamAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  in Blazor

```
[DefaultTypeParam("TValue", typeof(bool))]
public partial class CheckComponenet<TValue> : BlazorComponent
```

Comment: What is your question ? Where do you define DefaultTypeParam ?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13619

Comment: I've asked you what is your question. And issue no. 13619 is not where you define your  DefaultTypeParam attribute. Please, remove both of your questions, and don't waste our time.

Comment: Please check this comment - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13619#issuecomment-527768288

Comment: That comment was a suggestion that was rejected. This is not a question.

Comment: My question - 

How to set default TValue in razor file

ex: @typeparam TValue = bool